# html cannot align table row by row

Tags: html, css

What I am trying is to display message row by row, and finally display a text box for input to send message, now the problem I faced is that I can display the message row by row, however the text box will be show near to the display message horizontally. The text box cannot be show at the bottom row of the page. Here is the unexpected result image. I tried many ways but seems cannot solve it. 
    [image: enter code here]

Edited: And I need to display incoming message on left side and outgoing message on the right hand side
[image]

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#CCFFEE">
            test() blah,blah,blah 2016-08-12 04:44:20
          </td>
          <td>
            <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80">
          </td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#CCFFEE">
                test() Hi 2016-08-12 04:43:16
              </td>
              <td>
                <img src="" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80">
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <tr>
      </table>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <table>
        <form action="/v1/reply" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();window.location.reload();" name="myForm">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="body" name="body" style="width:700px;height:50px;">
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="submit" style="width:100px;height:50px;" id="sent_1" value="Send">Submit</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <br>
        </form>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your form cannot sit inside the table in that way. I suggest first validating your html, which will make it easier. Assuming you move the form outside the table, you can wrap the previous table and this form and position the form to be absolute, bottom, right positioned, if you want it to be at the bottom right at all times, but it's not clear what the 'desired' outcome should look like.

Comment: Can we try `div` instead of `table`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-table` then `float:right;` and `float:left` if you want a `<td>` to be wider than the other `<td>`, use `colspan`. All and more properties and attributes are used in the Snippet below:

#### SNIPPET

```css
.msg {
  display: inline-table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.input {
  width: 100%;
}
img {
   display: block;
   padding:0 80% 0 0;
   margin: 0 auto 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%">
      <form action="http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php" method="post" name="myForm">
        <table class='left msg'>
          <tr>
            <td colspan='2' bgcolor="#CCFFEE">
              test() blah,blah,blah 2016-08-12 04:44:20
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80">
            </td>

            <tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan='2' bgcolor="#CCFFEE">
                  test() Hi 2016-08-12 04:43:16
                </td>
                <td>
                  <img src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80">
                </td>

                <tr>
        </table>
        <table class='right msg'>
          <tr>
            <td colspan='2' bgcolor="#CCFFEE">
              test() blah,blah,blah 2016-08-12 04:44:20
            </td>
            <td>
              <img src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80">
            </td>

            <tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan='2' bgcolor="#CCFFEE">
                  test() Hi 2016-08-12 04:43:16
                </td>
                <td>
                  <img src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" alt="Smiley face" height="80" width="80">
                </td>

                <tr>
        </table>
        <table class='input msg'>

          <tr>
            <td colspan='5'>
              <input type="text" id="body" name="body" style="width:100%;height:50px;">
            </td>
            <td>

              <input type='submit' style="width:100px;height:50px;" id="sent_1" value="Submit">
            </td>
          </tr> 


        </table>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Twitter Bootstrap in this,

insert `<div class="clearfix"></div>`

just before

```
<table>
    <form action="/v1/reply" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();window.location.reload();" name="myForm">

            <tr><td><input type="text" id="body" name="body" style="width:700px;height:50px;"></td>
                <td><button type="submit" style="width:100px;height:50px;" id="sent_1" value="Send">Submit</button></td>
            </tr><br>
    </form>
</table>
```

Comment: The OP did not indicate using bootstrap nor is the question tagged for it. This should probably be a comment.

Comment: Boaz, thanks for comment. But I think sysquare suggest a good way for me cause I even not knowing using Bootstrap.

Comment: Accept my answer please

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
table,
tr{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I think I may have not describe my scenario clearly, I need to display incoming message in left and outgoing message on right. I think the solution not completely suit for the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If the `table` is not compulsory for you, then you can use `flex-box`

You can understand the advantage of using `flexbox` after executing the following code snippet.
It is more customisable and in **my `html` code, The position of image is before message. But in the output for sent message, image is coming after message.**

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
img{
  width: 35px;
}
.reciever{
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.sender{
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.sent, .recieve{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.sent{
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
form{
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
input{
  width: 85%;
  height: 20px;
}
button{
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row sender">
 <div class="sent">
  <img src="http://www.carderator.com/assets/avatar_placeholder_small.png" alt="">
  <span>sent message 1</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row reciever">
 <div class="recieve">
  <img src="http://www.quantumphotonics.uottawa.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/portrait_placeholder.png" alt="">
  <span>recieved message 1</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row sender">
 <div class="sent">
  <img src="http://www.carderator.com/assets/avatar_placeholder_small.png" alt="">
  <span>sent message 2</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row reciever">
 <div class="recieve">
  <img src="http://www.quantumphotonics.uottawa.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/portrait_placeholder.png" alt="">
  <span>recieved message 2</span>
 </div>
</div><div class="row sender">
 <div class="sent">
  <img src="http://www.carderator.com/assets/avatar_placeholder_small.png" alt="">
  <span>sent message 3</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row reciever">
 <div class="recieve">
  <img src="http://www.quantumphotonics.uottawa.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/portrait_placeholder.png" alt="">
  <span>recieved message 3</span>
 </div>
</div>
<form action="">
 <input type="text" >
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the working **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6b6fnbp0/)**